# How to get element inside parent div

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I want help about to get element by name from parent div.

Example

```html
<div class="Car">
    <div class="CarSepcification">
        <img src="Car.jpg" name="CarImg">
        <span class="CarName">BMW X5</span>
        <span class="CarDetails">BMW X5 4.4L 2016 Black</span>
        <div class="CarPrice">
            <span class="Price">38,750</span><span>EUR</span>
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" value="BMW" name="hdf_car"/>
                <img src="Add.jpg" onclick="AddCar(this)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In above example I have image, name, and price of car. How can I get car name, img and price also for hidden field value by `getElementbyName` in function `Addcar()` ?

I want it using Javascript not jQuery.

Comment: Use [`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) until you arrive at the element on which you want to call `getElementByName`

Comment: Use `var parent= document.querySelector ('div.CarSepcification'); var element = parent.querySelector ('img [name=CarImg]')`.. Similarly you do for other two items..

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements using class names.

Hope this helps!

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByName('CarImg')[0].src);
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('CarName')[0].innerHTML)
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('Price')[0].innerHTML)
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0].value)
```

```html
<div class="Car">
    <div class="CarSepcification">
        <img src="Car.jpg" name="CarImg">
        <span class="CarName">BMW X5</span>
        <span class="CarDetails">BMW X5 4.4L 2016 Black</span>
        <div class="CarPrice">
            <span class="Price">38,750</span><span>EUR</span>
            <div >
                <input class="hidden" type="hidden" value="BMW" name="hdf_car"/>//add a identifier to access the element from the DOM
                <img src="Add.jpg" onclick="AddCar(this)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function AddCar(xxx) {
  console.log('This: ',xxx);
  var aCars = document.getElementsByClassName('Car');
  // console.log(aCars);
  for (var i =0; i < aCars.length; i++) {
    var car = aCars[i];
      // console.log(car);
      var obj = {
        img : car.getElementsByClassName('CarImg')[0].src,
          name : car.getElementsByClassName('CarName')[0].innerHTML,
          detail : car.getElementsByClassName('CarDetails')[0].innerHTML,
          price :car.getElementsByClassName('Price')[0].innerHTML,
          hidden :  car.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value,
      }
      console.log(obj);

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="Car">
    <div class="CarSepcification">
        <img src="Car.jpg" name="CarImg" class="CarImg">
        <span class="CarName">BMW X5</span>
        <span class="CarDetails">BMW X5 4.4L 2016 Black</span>
        <div class="CarPrice">
            <span class="Price">38,750</span><span>EUR</span>
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" value="BMW" name="hdf_car"/>
                <img src="Add.jpg" onclick="AddCar(this)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Car">
    <div class="CarSepcification">
        <img src="Car.jpg" name="CarImg" class="CarImg">
        <span class="CarName">BMW X125</span>
        <span class="CarDetails">123BMW X5 4.4L 2016 Black</span>
        <div class="CarPrice">
            <span class="Price">138,750</span><span>EUR</span>
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" value="BMW2" name="hdf_car"/>
                <img src="Add.jpg" onclick="AddCar(this)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Better?

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: Thank you kolzar, I tried this but if I have more than <div class="Car">...</div>    <div class="Car">...</div>     <div class="Car">...</div>  

and each div has same details [ img / car name / price ] but I want to use  (this) ?? is there any way to do that

Comment: I edit the post and i don't think you can use the "this" because capture the same tag. Then you can't disambiguate the tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's better

Comment: you are welcome, please mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
let parentDiv = [...document.querySelectorAll('.Car')];
parentDiv.forEach((div) => {
   let carImg = 
   div.getElementByTagName('img').getAttribute('name');
   let carName = div.getElementByTagName('span'). 
   [0].innerText;
   let carDetails = div.getElementByTagName('span'). 
   [1].innerText;

  And so on

});
```

Answer (score -2):

Meanwhile Monica's answer is good, I feel like `document.querySelector()` is more suitable for... everything, when you're referencing elements from the DOM. Also `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array, which in this example, is useless. Also, `querySelector()` is pretty familliar since you reference an ID or a class or an input by its name like you do in CSS. Like:
`document.querySelector(".Car");` or `document.querySelector("input[name='hdf_car']")`.

Comment: Thank you I tried this but if I have more than <div class="Car">...</div> <div class="Car">...</div> <div class="Car">...</div> and each div has same details [ img / car name / price ] but I want to use (this) ?? is there any way to do that